# How to use google plus into a vuejs ionic project

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, google-plus, ionic-vue

I'm working on an app with Vue.js and Ionic (Beta) and with capacitor.
In all tutorial, we need to store variable with the cordova cli.
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`

But I don't have the cordova cli.. I tried to store variable in package.json like this :

```
 "cordova": {
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "xxx"
      }
  }
```

But it's don't work.. With no error alert or message.. I don't know how I can make it work..

Thx for your help !

Comment: did you figure out?